# inDesign plugin for once solution app development

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, ios4, app-store

I've spent a good few weeks looking at different options for creating an app for a magazine.
I've looked at Adobe Digital Publishing, Aquafadas, PadMan, WoodWing and Mag+ but haven't found a suitable solution.
My requirements are to take existing artwork (produced in inDesign) and produce
1. An iPhone App,
2. An iPad App
3. A cross browser compatible web version.

My question - is there one of these type of solutions that can produce all 3 versions that I require?

Another option I considered was to create a HTML5 / Javascript version of the magazine and hire a developer to make the 3 versions. This would be time consuming for me as, although I'd have the content for the magazine, I'd be coding from scratch. Any suggestions from someone who has created an app with a web version available too?

Answer (score 0):

Our project on Kickstarter will export HTML5 directly from InDesign:
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ajarproductions/indesign-to-html5

We hope to include [web app](http://www.apple.com/webapps/whatarewebapps.html) functionality as well.